# php mis-config cause joomla login to fail?

Tags: php, joomla, authentication, config

I was attempting to clone a Joomla site, I had exported the database from the original, and was attempting to use phpmyadmin to import it into the db for the new site. The DB was around 75mb so the import kept timing out. I (foolishy) logged in to my hosting control panel and started tweaking settings (memory_limit, mac_execution_time, max_input time, etc), putting them at larger and larger values to import the db (which never worked, probably because i didn't restart apache).

This morning I used MySql Workbench to open the SQL Export file I had done from phpmyadmin, run the query, and import it that way. This worked I had my database and setup my site duplicate for revisions.

Then gradually throughout the day I began to lose backend functionality across all of my sites (roughly a dozen or so, most of which I hadn't touched). First K2 wouldn't filter or save, it would jump back to admin control panel. I started checking and noticed this on all site. After couple hours of that, I started to lose admin login capability altogether. One by one, I couldn't login, it just reset to blank fields. I checked the couple of sites I have front end login enabled and when I try to login there I get "invalid token".

I checked jos_plugins, my 'User - Joomla' is published. My name/id are still in jos_users and I'm still typed as super admin. The php settings were reset (i let the pros at my hosting company do that), and services restarted. That didn't work, and neither then did a hard reboot.

Can anyone think of anything in the php config I may have tweaked that would cause this? Here's a few settings that seem to count (or I remember messing with) and their value. I must be missing something here.

```
memory_limit: 128M
upload_max_filesize: 64MB
max_execution_time: 30
max_input_time: 60
session.cache_expire: 180
session.cookie_domain: blank (default server name then I believe?)
session.cookie_lifetime: 0 (expires browser restart?)
session.gc_maxlifetime: 1400
```

Anything else I should look at? Can anyone help? Truly desperate here.

Comment: which joomla version?

Comment: what joomla version you are using ? You mention that your are `Truly desperate` but you dont respond

Comment: Sorry! I checked on my phone all night but it never updated. I'm running Joomla 1.5.2 I believe, and php 5.2.9.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, operator error! I had used incorrect shorthand for upload_max_filesize (MB instead of M). Apparantly it makes a difference. :) I do appreciate you responding Deonia and sorry to have wasted your time. From https://www.php.net/ini.core

> Note:
> PHP allows shortcuts for bit values, including K (kilo), M (mega) and G (giga). PHP will do the conversions automatically if you use any of these. Be careful not to exceed the 32 bit signed integer limit (if you're using 32bit versions) as it will cause your script to fail."